# How to upload audio files via Javascript to S3 private bucket via presigned-URL?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

my goal is to upload audio-files to AWS S3. The S3 bucket should remain private/block public access and the content is served via a CloudFront distribution. This can be achieved by using a pre-signed URL and I am able to upload a .wav file via a curl command to the URL obtained, hence I assume my issue can be located in the upload function or the HTML form, but wasn't able to identify it since last week.

On-clicking the upload button I receive the following error in the console:

```
code 501, message Unsupported method ('PUT')
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2022 14:23:13] "PUT /[object%20Promise] HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

Clicking upload on the cloudfront distribution URL yields to no change in the console.  Chrome on a localhost also gives no feedback, Firefox on localhost results in:

```
error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
```

I have read that browsers only allow GET request - but how can I then upload?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Audio transcription 14:53!</title>
        
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.410.0.min.js"></script>
      
        <h1>Audio file upload  14:31</h1>
        <form class="form" id="myForm">
          <input type="file" id="inputFile"  accept="audio/*">
          <br>
          <button type="submit" id="submitButton" > Upload </button>
        </form>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

**index.js**

```
const BUCKET_NAME = 'XYZ';
const accessKeyId = 'XYZ';
const secretAccessKey ='XYZ';

//Updates SDK with access keys from above
AWS.config.update({
    region:'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey
});

//initiate S3
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01', signatureVersion: 'v4', });

//call getSignedURL
const obtainURL = async () => {
    try {
        //getObject defines for which Object the URL should be
        //change getObject to putObject for upload
        //Key defines the name of the S3 object
        const url = await s3.getSignedUrl("putObject",{
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: 'test.wav',
            Expires: 5*60,
        });
        return url;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

// Upload files with fetch

const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
const inputFile = document.getElementById("inputFile");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    const endpoint = obtainURL();
  
    //create form data object, which will hold file once it's chosen, then passes it into the request
    const formData = new FormData();


    //inpFile is they key, the second parameter is the data to be send
    formData.append("inputFile", inputFile.files[0]);

    //now that we have the formData object containing our data, we can now post it using fetch
 
fetch(endpoint, {

        method: "PUT",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "audio/wav",
                    "Content-Length": formData.length
           }
        
    }).catch(error => {
                console.log('error', error)
    });
    
  
});
```